# Do not print "not found" when something is found

Tags: java

I am trying to do this project and for some reason I am having an issue that for the life of me I can not solve.

```
public static void printlist(String n){
    for(int i=0; i<  roomlist.size(); i++){
        if(roomlist.get(i).name.equals(n)){
            System.out.println("Room Name: " + roomlist.get(i).name + " state:     " + roomlist.get(i).state);
            System.out.println("Description: " + roomlist.get(i).desc);
            System.out.println("Creatures in Room: " + roomlist.get(i).Fred());
            if(roomlist.get(i).north != null){
                System.out.println("North Neighbor: " + roomlist.get(i).north.name);
            }
            if (roomlist.get(i).south !=null){
                System.out.println("South Neighbor: " + roomlist.get(i).south.name);
            }
            if (roomlist.get(i).east !=null){
                System.out.println("East Neighbor: " + roomlist.get(i).east.name);
            }
            if (roomlist.get(i).west !=null){
                System.out.println("West Neighbor: " + roomlist.get(i).west.name);
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Room " + n + " does not exist!");
}
```

Right now even if it finds the Room object in the ArrayList it still prints "Room " + n + " does not exist!" I need it to only print that if the room is not found in the ArrayList

Answer (score 3):

The reason it happens is because the `Not found` message is the last statement of your method. You should instead return from the method as soon as you found your element and you printed your wanted messages.

For example assuming each room has a unique name:

```
...
if (roomlist.get(i).name.equals(n)) {
    ...
    if (roomlist.get(i).west != null) {
       System.out.println("West Neighbor: " + roomlist.get(i).west.name);
    }
    return;
}
...
```

Comment: I don't think he wants the `return` in the cases to print neighboring rooms.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: There's no `if-else` that is applicable here.

Comment: By the way, since the used collection might be a list (according to the name), this solution won't find and print duplicate rooms with the same name.

Comment: I wrote that I assume that each room has a unique name. But from the code and the messages, it appears that the OP probably uses the name to identify a room.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `System.out.println("Room " + n + " does not exist!");` will always be executed, because there is nothing stopping it

Assuming that there can be more then one neighboring room, it might be easier to use a simple flag to indicate if any rooms where found

```
public static void printlist(String n){
    boolean foundRoom = false;
    for(int i=0; i<  roomlist.size(); i++){
        if(roomlist.get(i).name.equals(n)){
            foundRoom = true;
            System.out.println("Room Name: " + roomlist.get(i).name + " state:     " + roomlist.get(i).state);
            System.out.println("Description: " + roomlist.get(i).desc);
            System.out.println("Creatures in Room: " + roomlist.get(i).Fred());
            if(roomlist.get(i).north != null){
                System.out.println("North Neighbor: " + roomlist.get(i).north.name);
            }
            if (roomlist.get(i).south !=null){
                System.out.println("South Neighbor: " + roomlist.get(i).south.name);
            }
            if (roomlist.get(i).east !=null){
                System.out.println("East Neighbor: " + roomlist.get(i).east.name);
            }
            if (roomlist.get(i).west !=null){
                System.out.println("West Neighbor: " + roomlist.get(i).west.name);
            }
        }

    }
    if (!foundRoom) {
        System.out.println("Room " + n + " does not exist!");
    }
}
```

You could probably optimise it by using a `List` of some kind to store the neighboring rooms in and checking the `size` at the end, but the basic idea remains the same...

Comment: This would print that the room doesn't exist if it does exist but has no neighbors, which doesn't seem as intended.

Comment: How?  If a room exists and "Neighbor" statement is printed, then the `System.out.println("Room " + n + " does not exist!");` can't be executed as `foundRoom` is `true`

Comment: Of course, but my point is that it is not the existence of its neighbors that determines the existence of the room as such. The room still exists, even if it has no neighbors. You should set `foundRoom` to true as soon as `name.equals(n)`.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Thank you, yes I picked that up and corrected it. We don't care about the neighbors, just the existence of the room itself

Comment: Indeed. I removed my downvote. I do have to say that I still think that @JuniorCompressor's answer is better, however, with explicit control transfer instead of using booleans to emulate control flow.

Comment: @Dolda2000 The only reason I don't like JuniorCompressor's  answer is I don't like `return` statements that appear in the middle of the code, as it's to easy to miss and it can break the flow of logic when you're trying to understand the functionality of the code.  I'm old school, I was taught that a function/method should have one entry and one exit point.  That's just me though.  Appreciate the feedback though

Comment: I disagree, but I can live with it as a difference in opinion. :)